# Не изменяются настройки визуализации

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, визуализация

Есть процедура, вызывающее окно настроек визуализации

```
procedure TfmTableData.menusettingsClick(Sender: TObject);
var i : integer;
    fmset : TfmSettings;
begin
  fmSet:=TfmSettings.Create(fmTableData);
  fmSet.edTitleForm.Text:='';
  //fmSettings:=TfmSettings.Create(fmShowData);
for i := 0 to TTableSpec(DBSchema.Tables.FindComponent({fmListOfTables.DisplayTable}databasetable)).Fields.ComponentCount-1 do
begin
  if (TTableSpec(DBSchema.Tables.FindComponent({fmListOfTables.DisplayTable}databasetable)).Fields.Components[i] is TFieldSpec) then
    begin
      fmSet.CheckListBox1.Items.Add(TFieldSpec(TTableSpec(DBSchema.Tables.FindComponent({fmListOfTables.DisplayTable}databasetable)).Fields.Components[i]).FieldName);
      fmSet.CheckListBox1.Checked[i]:=DBGrid1.Columns[i].Visible;
    end;
end;
  fmSet.NameFormOwner:=databasetable;
  fmSet.Cont:=fmTableData;
  fmSet.Show();
end;
```

Есть также процедура, изменяющая визуализацию окна, для которого было вызвано окно настроек визуализации, которая срабатывает по щелчку на пункте CheckListBox, в результате которого соответствующий столбец таблицы перестает быть видимым

```
procedure TfmSettings.CheckListBox1ClickCheck(Sender: TObject);
var querystr : string;
    i, j : integer;
    TitleArray : array[0..1000] of string;
    WidthArray : array[0..1000] of integer;
begin
    querystr:='select ';
    for I := 0 to fmTableData.DBGrid1.Columns.Count-1 do
      begin
        TitleArray[i]:=fmTableData{ShowData}.DBGrid1.Columns[i].Title.Caption;
        WidthArray[i]:=fmTableData{ShowData}.DBGrid1.Columns[i].Width;
      end;
    for I := 0 to CheckListBox1.Items.Count-1 do
      begin
         querystr:=querystr+ConvertNameField(CheckListBox1.Items[i])+', ';
      end;
    Delete(querystr, Length(querystr)-1, 1);
    querystr:=querystr+'from '+NameFormOwner;
      {for i := 0 to MainWindow.ComponentCount-1 do
      begin
      if MainWindow.Components[i] is TfmTableData then
          if (MainWindow.Components[i] as TfmTableData) then}

      TfmTableData(Panel1.Owner.Owner).IBQuery1.SQL.Clear;
      TfmTableData(Panel1.Owner.Owner).IBQuery1.SQL.Add(querystr);
      TfmTableData(Panel1.Owner.Owner).IBQuery1.Open;
    for i := 0 to CheckListBox1.Items.Count-1 do
    begin
      if not CheckListBox1.Checked[i] then

      TfmTableData(Panel1.Owner.Owner).DBGrid1.Columns[{CheckListBox1.ItemIndex}i].Visible :=CheckListBox1.Checked[i];
      //not(fmShowData.DBGrid1.Columns[CheckListBox1.ItemIndex].Visible);
    end;
    for j:=0 to fmTableData{ShowData}.DBGrid1.Columns.Count-1 do
      begin
        for i:=0 to CheckListBox1.Items.Count-1 do
          begin
            if TfmTableData(Panel1.Owner.Owner){fmTableData}{ShowData}.DBGrid1.Columns[j].Title.Caption=TitleArray[i] then
              TfmTableData(Panel1.Owner.Owner){fmTableData}{ShowData}.DBGrid1.Columns[j].Width:=WidthArray[i];
          end;
      end;
      //end;
end;
```

Но в результате визуализация не меняется.столбцы не перестают быть видимыми после отмены выделения соответствующих пунктов в CheckListBox.
Формируется sql запрос с использованием пунктов CheckListBox, который выполняется в окне владельце окна настроек визуализации. Затем в зависимости от состояния соответствующих пунктов CheckListBox соответствующие столбцы перестают быть видимыми. Почему? Помогите устранить ошибку.

Comment: А зачем вы делаете эту проверку __if not CheckListBox1.Checked[i] then__, если дальше все равно устанавливаете видимость столбца по значению __CheckListBox1.Checked[i]__ ?

Comment: @teanЫЧ у вас только один вопрос "а зачем?" возник? я перестал считать на втором десятке... ужс.

Comment: @Yura Ivanov, вы считаете мои комменты? ужс.

Comment: @teanЫЧ Нет. Я про код. У меня просто возникла масса вопросов "зачем". например, зачем обращаться к вызывающей форме через Panel1.Owner.Owner если есть fmSet.Cont? Или зачем формировать и выполнять запрос в настройках, наверняка такое формирование уже есть в главной форме (по хорошему в датамодуле) - копипаст? Или зачем вообще снова делать запрос если мы хотим скрыть пару столбцов... и т.д.

Comment: @Yura Ivanov, а, тогда прошу прощения. Не так понял ваш вопрос.  
Я просто убегал на обед и быстренько написал первое, что бросилось в глаза, и что, на мой взгляд, относилось непосредственно к сабжу)

Comment: @Yura Ivanov @teanЫЧ запрос делается потому что приложение еще к тому же сериализуется и при сериализации делается запрос только на видимые столбцы и если после сериализации количество видимых столбцов увеличится то возникнет ошибка. А насчет fmSet.Cont - так это было первоначальным вариантом, который тоже не работал.